# Cmake can't link to SFML

Tags: windows, cmake, sfml

My cmake see the SFML,but don't want to use it.Help pls.
CmakeLists in main folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(sfml-lab-1)
add_subdirectory(00)
```

CmakeLists in 00 folder

```
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS graphics audio  PATHS C:/SFML-2.5.1/)
add_executable(00 main.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(00 sfml-graphics sfml-audio)
```

What cmd says:

```
d:\try_cmake>cmake --build .
CMake Warning at 00/CMakeLists.txt:1 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package "SFML" that is compatible
with requested version "2.5.1".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/SFML-2.5.1/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake, version: 2.5.1 (64bit)



-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/try_cmake
[ 50%] Building CXX object 00/CMakeFiles/00.dir/main.cpp.obj
D:\try_cmake\00\main.cpp:1:29: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: If you use version `2.5` instead of `2.5.1`, does it work?

Comment: Are you actually building your application as a 64 bit build? The installed version of SFML provides a 64 bit config, so if you configured your build for 32 bit (as is the default on certain Visual Studio versions, for instance), it won't be able to use that library.

Answer (score 0):

Helped switching to 32-bit version instead of 64-bit

Comment: That probably means your SFML binaries were 32 bit.